# Is there any way to fill controls from a class library of visual studio?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have one aspx page Invoice.aspx,its user control page  Invoice.ascx.In ascx page I am required to call a function which is in  classlibrary to fill the controls, having passed their control IDs to the function.I thought of using FindControl function but when I type

```
 using System.Web.UI.Controls;
```

in my classlibrary,it is giving me error.Is there any other way to fill the controls? please suggest me. Thanks in advance!

Comment: `it is giving me error`. Care to explain..

Comment: Have you added a reference to `System.Web`?

Comment: The type or namespace "UI" does not exist in the namespace 'System.Web'

Comment: I doubt if i can use UI in class library.Is there any other way I can do it? I am not allowed to do the work of filling the textboxes in ascx page.I need to call a function which has to be in a library.Is my approach correct?

Answer (score 0):

Please do following steps.

1. Go to project setting and change target framework. ( do not use client profile. use .Net Framework 4.0)
2. now add reference to System.Web

It will work for me in past so it will work for you.

Comment: It is already set to .Net Framework 4.0.but I should be able to write "using System.Web.UI.Controls" right?

Comment: You have to add reference of System.Web

Comment: It may possible that directive is System.Web.UI.WebControls

Answer (score 0):

```
[MessageContract(IsWrapped = true, WrapperName = "setData")]
public class setDataRequest
{
    public setDataRequest() 
    {
        ConnectionInfo = Base.Service.Configuration.DefaultConnectionInfo;
    }

    [MessageBodyMember(Order = 0, Name = "connectionInfo")]
    [XmlElement(Form = XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
    public ConnectionInfo ConnectionInfo { get; set; }

    [MessageBodyMember(Order = 1, Name = "generic")]
    [XmlElement(Form = XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
    public GenericSet Generic { get; set; }
}
```